# Spring Boot Mysql query to get all records based on the @query value

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I am trying to retreive all records from a MySQL table using spring boot JPA. Following is the repositry definition

MovieRepository class

```
@Query("From MovieEntity m, TheaterMovieShowEntity tms, TheaterEntity t where t.city=?1 and t.theaterid=tms.theaterid and m.movieid=tms.movieid and t.seatsavailable>=?2")
    List<Movie> getMoviesDetails(String cityName, int noOfTickets)throws MovieException;
```

MovieService Class

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesDetails(String cityName, int noOfTickets)throws MovieException{
        List<Movie>moviesIntheCityList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        **moviesIntheCityList = (List<Movie>) movieRepository.getMoviesDetails(cityName, noOfTickets);**
        System.out.println("in the getMoviesDetails after querying"+moviesIntheCityList); // This is null
        return moviesIntheCityList;
    }
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your Repository File use this way

`List<Movie> findByCityNameAndNoOfTickets(String cityName, int noOfTickets)`

refer [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
List<Movie> movieRepository.findByCityNameAndNoOfTickets(String cityName, int noOfTickets);
```

in your MovieRepository. And then call it. In Spring Data JPA if you follow proper naming conventions then you got to only declare the name of method in Repository and JPA will implement it for you.

Comment: Here the 2 query parameters are  in 2 different tables. cityName is in table Movie while noOfTickets is in table Theater.  How to handle this  tpe of query which needs to filter results based on values across 2 different tables.